# Sending email from java

Tags: java, web-applications, smtp

I am trying to send confirmation email to users of my web application, but i am getting the following error:

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This is my java class:

```
package it.bcsoft.onlinestore.mail;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class EmailSender {

    public static boolean sendEmail(String from, String pass, String message, String[] to)
    {
        String host="smtp.gmail.com";
        Properties props= System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage mime= new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            mime.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress= new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for(int i=0; i<to.length; i++)
            {
                toAddress[i]= new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<toAddress.length;i++)
            {
                mime.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }
            mime.setSubject("Mail from onlinestore");
            mime.setText(message);
            Transport transport= session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(mime, mime.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            return true;
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do not have any SMTP Server installed on my PC and i am using java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right port. To use Gmail's SMTP server via TLS, you have to use port `587`.

[Source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) on how to build up a SMTP connection to Gmail.

Comment: i tried already with all three ports "587,25 and 465" same thing

Comment: Have a look at the blog post i just added and try to connect to the SMTP server the way it describes.

Comment: I tried both examples, TLS and SSL it gives me always the same error